# Vanilla JS - making static chart

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization

I have a bit of a weird question. I'm looking to write some JS that is compatible with a ***metaverse*** (https://www.cryptovoxels.com/play) and I'm creating interactive experiences inside that are driven by live data and JS. Would be really cool if I figured out how to show a chart made in JS. What I'm doing is highly experimental, and I don't have any traditional html to manipulate, so doing something like `Document.getElementById()` won't work, and there is a different built-in function to access elements that I can use to modify attributes of the in-game objects like the url of an image.

It's very likely this is totally impossible, but I'm basically looking for a way to make a static png/jpeg chart using client side vanilla js (I can copy/paste code from a CDN script but doesn't always work - worked for tensorflow so sometimes depending on the code it does). I cannot work with .svg, it doesn't work in this environment. Documentation for the tool I am writing my script inside of: https://wiki.cryptovoxels.com/en/Scripting/Scripting

So far I have tried these without much success at all: D3, Google Charts, ChartJS, FusionCharts, Plotly

I realize this is a really odd question, but if anyone has any thoughts around how I could do this would be much appreciated and would let me make some crazy cool stuff.

Comment: some char js scripts are displaying the result in a `canvas` element. You can easily get a `base64`  string with `canvasElement.toDataURL()`

Comment: @Ricky In short words do you want to display the chart image format only when the page loads?